# Best way to combine the same index of multiple arrays

Tags: javascript

I have an array containing three arrays, each containing two elements. I want to alter it so that I have two new arrays, each containing the same indices from the three original arrays. And one of the three original arrays contains objects as its elements and I want to flatten them as well and only contain their values in the new arrays.

This is what I have so far:

```js
const results = [
  [0, 1],
  [{a: 'a1a1a1', b: 'b1b1b1'}, {a: 'a2a2a2', b: 'b2b2b2'}],
  ['zero', 'one']
];

let values = [];

let num = 1;

while (num >= 0) {
  let cardVals = results.map(c => c[num]);
  values.unshift(cardVals);
  num--;
};

console.log(values);
```

My console log looks like this currently:

```
[ [ 0, { a: 'a1a1a1', b: 'b1b1b1' }, 'zero' ],
  [ 1, { a: 'a2a2a2', b: 'b2b2b2' }, 'one' ] ]
```

But I want it to look like this:

```
[ [ 0, 'a1a1a1', 'b1b1b1', 'zero' ],   
[ 1, 'a2a2a2', 'b2b2b2', 'one' ] ]
```

I could check if it's an array or a js object in my map, but is there a way to do it without doing that?

Comment: You can't do this with `map()`, since it always returns an array with the same number of elements as the input.

Comment: So what would be the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to check whether the element is an object. If it is, you need to use `Object.values()` to get an array of the values. You can then use `concat()` to concatenate these to the current element of the result.

```js
const results = [
  [0, 1],
  [{
    a: 'a1a1a1',
    b: 'b1b1b1'
  }, {
    a: 'a2a2a2',
    b: 'b2b2b2'
  }],
  ['zero', 'one']
];

let values = [];

for (let i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
  let cardValues = [];
  results.forEach(el => {
    if (typeof el[i] == 'object') {
      cardValues = cardValues.concat(Object.values(el[i]));
    } else {
      cardValues.push(el[i]);
    }
  });
  values.push(cardValues);
}

console.log(values);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one solution:

```js
const results = [ [0, 1],
                  [{a: 'a1a1a1', b: 'b1b1b1'}, {a: 'a2a2a2', b: 'b2b2b2'}],
                  ['zero', 'one']
                ];

let values = [];

results[0].forEach((_, i) => { // assume all elements have same dimension as first
  values.push(
    results.map(result => 
      typeof result[i] == 'object' ? Object.values(result[i]) : // if object, get its values
                                     result[i]                  // otherwise, get the current value
    ).flat()  // flatten any Object.values()
  )
});

console.log(values);
```

Comment: Consider reduce over foreach/push?

Comment: @evolutionxbox, unsure how `reduce` could simplify my code.  Would be interested if you posted a solution.